# Google Maps v2 Android - How to stop a user placing a marker out of the map bounds?

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm using the Google Maps from GMS to create an Android app similar to GeoGuessr, but I've been notified by users that if you place a marker outside of the bounds at the top or the bottom of the map (in the 'chequered' area), it sets a latitude ~150km away from the actual location

I don't want to limit actual play, so ideally I'd like to set a boundary beyond which that the user can't place a marker
I tried using the Bounds in Maps, with the following results:

```
LatLng ne = new LatLng(85, 180);           
LatLng sw = new LatLng(-85, -180);

LatLngBounds Bounds = new LatLngBounds(sw,ne);
```

This one resulted in an out of bounds every time

```
LatLngBounds Bounds = mMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;
new LatLngBounds(sw,ne);
```

This one resulted in no change, presumably because it's setting the same bounds (mMap is the currently initialised map)

As an example, here's a screenshot of what I mean:
[image: Example, marker is out of bounds of map]

Any ideas of what I could do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the surface of planets and other spherical objects -180 is the same as 180. You need to calculate a value that is smaller by "one bit" than 180.

```
double smallerThan180 = Double.longBitsToDouble(Double.doubleToLongBits(180.0) - 1);
LatLng southWest = new LatLng(-85.0, -180.0);
LatLng northEast = new LatLng(85.0, smallerThan180);
LatLngBounds boundsOfDrawnWorld = new LatLngBounds(southWest, northEast);
```

Anyway, why you just don't check the value of latitude?

```
if (-85.0 <= somePoint.latitude && somePoint.latitude <= 85.0) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: This worked a dream. Using the first suggestion and checking if it's within the bounds using boundsOfDrawnWorld.contains(point) and the problem is solved